# What is the right way to validate fields in Angular template?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactive form and each field is displaying validation message if it is not valid. When I saw I had this check  `!!(!form.get(field)?.valid && form.get(field)?.touched);` in each input I have decided to extract this logic to a function. It did work, but as I read it is not a good practice to use function/getters inside the template as it retriggers change detection and as I added console.log to the function I saw it was called too many times, without any justification.

What is the right way to do this validation, without having to trigger changed detection for nothing, and causing performance issues in the long term?

Comment: Multiple solutions possible. Easiest is probably to hold a lookup object in your component which can hold the valid state for each control, and then simply listen to form valuechanges and in that, find your invalid controls, set their refs in the object and simply use that object in your template.

Comment: @MikeOne can you provide an example please?

Comment: Sorry, I’m on mobile at the moment..

Answer (score 2):

```
<mat-hint *ngIf="(CustomerForm.controls['userMobile'].invalid && (CustomerForm.controls['userMobile'].dirty || CustomerForm.controls['userMobile'].touched))">
   <mat-error *ngIf="CustomerForm.controls['userMobile'].errors.required">
      {{ 'REQUIRED' | translate:lang }}
   </mat-error>
   <mat-error *ngIf="CustomerForm.controls['userMobile'].errors.pattern">
      {{ 'ERROR_INVALID_MOBILE' | translate:lang }} {{'LABEL_EX' | translate: lang}} {{patternDetails?.phoneNumberFormat}})
   </mat-error>
   <mat-error *ngIf="CustomerForm.controls['userMobile'].errors.minlength">
      {{ 'ERROR_MOBILE_DIGITS' | translate:lang }}{{customerRules.MOBILE_MIN_LENGTH}}{{ 'DIGITS' | translate:lang}}
   </mat-error>
</mat-hint>
```

Answer (score 0):

Introducing Angular Material and using `<mat-form-field>` will be your desired behavior.

Example for required field.

html:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <mat-form-field>
    <label>
      <input matInput formControlName="field">
    </label>
    <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('field')?.errors?.required">
      Required field.
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

ts:

```
this.form.get('field')?.setValidators([Validators.required]);
```

Comment: I was probasbly not clear, but my goal was to avoid this "form.get('field')?.errors?.required is the template